# Web browser address included in os.getcwd() in custom url application

Tags: python, windows, browser, custom-url

I am using windows 7 and python 2.7
I am launching an **application using custom url**.
Within app code I want to know the path of the directory, this application is placed i.e.
it is placed in C:\Program Files (x86)\myapp\auth\custom.exe

So I used `path = os.getcwd()` to get, `path = C:\Program Files (x86)\myapp\auth`
but I am getting different paths according to web browser used for launching custom url application

For Mozilla, it is coming `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox`
For Chrome,  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\35.0.1916.153`

So, how to get correct directory address

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
[test@test ~]$ cat /tmp/test.py
import os

print os.path.split(__file__)

[test@test ~]$ python /tmp/test.py
('/tmp', 'test.py')
```

This might be solve your problem.

Comment: I am geeing error as `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`

Comment: I had written this code in custom.py file. Then made exe of it. Aligned it to custom url. Then it is showing this error

Comment: This code is working in eclipse. But when application in launched through custom url protocol, browser details is included in path which is causing issue. I am getting same error

Comment: Perhaps this is something to do with the "create an executable" step. How are you doing that?